# Pyserial, no response from device

Tags: python, pyserial

I am trying to communicate with a device using pyserial on Win7 with python 3.5. I am able to connect to the correct port 'COM4', however all other communication is ignored. What I did was:

```
from serial import *
s = Serial('COM4', stopbits=2)  # All other settings are default
```

No errors up to this point. But I received an error with the following line:

```
>> s.write('REM')  # Should put the device in 'Remote' mode
TypeError: unicode strings are not supported, please encode to bytes.
```

So I changed it to this:

```
>> s.write(b'REM')
3
```

And then it returns the number of characters of the string I tried to send to the device. If I would try 'S1' for example it would return 2. The device does not respond to the command and also does not give an error. I think the lack of communication is caused by changing the string to bytes, but I am not sure. Does anybody have a brilliant idea that could solve my mystery?